# find user's email transaction history in CentOs?

Tags: centos, email

is it possible, like in title, to find a particular user's email transaction history in CentOs? Tried `/var/log/maillog` but doesn't seems like it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not in the default configuration. First, log files will get rotated really quickly so you loose history, and secondly there is nothing that really prevents a user from using another mail server to send mail, although this gets increasingly uncommon due to spam filtering issues.

Comment: in the default configuration, is there a backup of emails stored somewhere? I am not sure what mail application CentOS is using as I am not really the adminstrator

Comment: First, if you are not the admin, you are wrong here to begin with (see our [faq]). Second, even the From/To mail history is a grey area from a privacy point of view, but reading the actual content is definitely something you need to discuss with your lawyer first.

Comment: I think u misunderstood me. I'm standing in for the administrator as he went for holidays and is uncontactable. I meant to say I did not configure the server hence I do not know here to look for the backups, if they do exists. I'm only asking because a user has complained about losing his emails...

Comment: In the default config of the mail server, there will be no backup of the mail data and we have no chance to know what system your admin used to create a backup.